# Decode all possible HTML entities?

Tags: php, html

We are working on a large amount of HTML data that needs to be converted to plain text. In the process we find not `html_entity_decode()` nor `htmlspecialchars_decode()` converts more than a few entities, e.g. `&lt`, `&gt`, `&quot;`, `$amp;` and that's it.

However in modern day HTML pages, there are quite some common entities:

```
&rarr;
&raquo;
&deg;
&reg;
&copy;
&apos;
&pound;
&yen;
&euro;
&sum;
&trade;
```

Which are all ignored by these functions.

What are my options to convert them to their corresponding character? I guess my best option would be to manually write a string replace function to do this?

Comment: ...and do not forgot to all other HTML entities: [https://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html] (HTML Entity List) :)

Comment: Why do you assume that they're ignored? https://3v4l.org/FEdRh shows that one I picked simply at random of those you said are ignore (`&deg;`) is decoded perfectly well

Comment: The only entity of those you've listed that isn't converted by default settings is `&apos;`, but even that will be converted with the correct flags: https://3v4l.org/rPCq5

Comment: @MarkBaker that wont work with `&apos;` - unless you add `ENT_HTML5` as a flag - it will also do other stupid shit unless you add `ENT_QUOTES` as a flag too (and it will do more stupid shit if you add the flag ENT_COMPAT)

Comment: @hanshenrik - I did post a comment about the correct flags, with a link to demonstrate

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

html_entity_decode should be the answer, it just has stupid defaults and thus you are probably using it wrong. try

```
$text=html_entity_decode($html,ENT_QUOTES|ENT_HTML5,'UTF-8')
```

alternatively,

```
$text=(@DOMDocument::loadHTML('<root>'.$html.'</root>'))->getElementsByTagName("root")->item(0)->textContent;
```

may also work

ps, i have no idea what all the downvotes are about, but i didnt read the comments either

Comment: Just tested this bit out myself, seems ENT_HTML5 is the answer for all possible HTML entities with html_entity_decode(). Stupid me used ENT_XML1 following one of the comments on the PHP page.